# How to deploy the Loopback in Weblogic server? Need simple explanation

Tags: loopbackjs

I am new to development. i created a small loop back application for my rest services.
its working fine in local .

I don't know how to deploy it the weblogic server. please advise step by step process for deployment.

FYI for Angular deployment we are using maven process to convert it war file

is any similar process available?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to run a loopback application inside a weblogic server. Loopback needs node.js runtime server to run, whereas weblogic only supports Java/J2EE applications.